# Under what criteria can a cost function be formed for the minimum time?

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics, control-theory, optimal-control

I have been reading about optimal control and in the various classic examples they usually come with the built-in cost function. But I have a question under what criteria was built that cost function ?, or what is the methodology that follow to find this functional ?.

So, if I have the following model of car-following with delay

$\ddot{x}_n(t+T)=\lambda[\dot{x}_{n-1}(t)-\dot{x}_n(t)], n=1,2,3,....,k,\quad T>0\text{ fixed}.$

I was working with the equations of the movement of a vehicle considering friction, where I got the next functional,

$J(\alpha(t))=-\int_{t_0}^{t_f}\frac{\mu}{m}\alpha(t)dt$,

where

- $\mu:$ Coefficient of friction
- $m:$ Mass of the vehicle
- $\alpha(t):$ Velocity (the control function)

In general, Under what criteria can you build the cost functional that minimizes travel time?

How can I associate the characteristics of the road (narrow way, wide way, presence of curves, etc.) for the construction of cost functional.

Merci beaucoup!

Comment: It's a bit difficult to understand your question (language), but if I understand correctly you're wondering how cost functions are chosen to minimize time, without directly putting time in the cost function? There are some things that will be directly equivalent (e.g. maximize velocity usually is), and then there are others that will be a good proxy (not equivalent in all cases, but often enough or close enough). And often, these proxies are the product of engineering. The trade-off will be ease of implementation, ability to actually measure the cost, safety-factors etc.

Comment: how the cost functions are chosen to minimize time, without directly putting the time in the cost function, depending on the friction for example?